# XML Parsing in Windows Phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8

i want to parse the xml file from the following url:"http://restservice.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/ghhf/cvr"

i am able to get the XDocument by using the following code :

```
private void Search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://restservice.schoolpundit.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/search_name/cvr";
    WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
    twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
    twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        return;
    XDocument doc = XDocument .Parse(e.Result);

    var list = from child in  doc.Descendants("Institutions_search_name")
               select new listrows {
                  inst_name=doc.Element("Inst_name").Value;
               };

     Listbox.ItemSource=list;
}
```

but it is not showing any Inst_name,actually it is not entering into the doc.Descendants("Institutions_search_name") it is not showing any exception also.if i did any mistake correct me.

Comment: Your code doesn't *use* `list` anywhere... it should still end up executing the `doc.Descendants` method, but you're not doing anything with the result. Did you check in the debugger that the parsing itself has succeeded? Note that your current code wouldn't even compile as you're trying to use a property called `value` when the actual property is called `Value`. There's no point in giving us something a bit like your code - you should give us *actual* code which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i want to bind that list to listBox. i edited the question check it now   and tell me the way to parse the xml.

Comment: You still haven't said whether you've checked in the debugger that the `XDocument.Parse` call worked. (And the code in your question is *horribly* format it. Please put a bit of effort into making it readable, with consistent indentation and without huge amounts of vertical whitespace for no reason.)

Comment: The code you've presented *still* wouldn't compile due to the `;` after `Value`, by the way. You should really have come up with a short but complete example which you could post *verbatim* before asking the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're just missing the namespace - although you're also calling `doc.Element` instead of `child.Element`. If you look at the XML, you'll see this in the root element:

```
 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService"
```

That means that every element which doesn't have a namespace explicitly specified is in that namespace.

Fortunately LINQ to XML makes this really easy to handle:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService";
var list = from child in doc.Descendants(ns + "Institutions_search_name")
           select new listrows {
               inst_name=child.Element(ns + "Inst_name").Value
           };
```

Although I'd probably do it without a query expression:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService";
var list = doc.Descendants(ns + "Institutions_search_name")
              .Select(x => new listrows { 
                         inst_name = child.Element(ns + "Inst_name").Value
                      });
```

In fact, given that you're *just* selecting a single string, I'd get rid of the `listrows` bit:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService";
var list = doc.Descendants(ns + "Institutions_search_name")
              .Select(x => child.Element(ns + "Inst_name").Value);
```

Also note that both `listrows` and `inst_name` violate .NET naming conventions - it's worth trying to be consistent with those conventions to make your code easier for everyone to read.

Comment: i am getting a NullReference Exception in     inst_name=child.Element(ns + "Inst_name").Value                          but there is text in  inst_name